# How find all files in directory c://

Tags: python, loops

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

files = []
for file in os.listdir():
    if file == "vol.py" or file == "thekey.key": ## ignore in the encryption - ransomware and thekey files
            continue
    if os.path.isfile(file):
            files.append(file)

print(files)
```

Comment: Can you please add the error you get or any information?

Comment: No error, code works well, code searches in the file path

Comment: If all is well, what is the purpose of the question?

Comment: Loop Search in c:// for files .txt

Comment: `os.listdir(pah/to/desired/directory)`?

Comment: Not working gives me an empty path

Answer (score 0):

From the title, I assume you are looking for the files in the C directory, but your python script is somewhere else so `os.listdir()` is returning the files for that directory.

You can simply pass the path of the directory in `os.listdir()` and get the directories for the C directory.

```py
path = 'C:\\'

os.listdir(path)
```

Comment: [ ]
gives me an empty path

Comment: Try now. Also are you using Windows operating system?